# 503 Service Unavailable with ambassador QOTM service

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes master/node setup in cent os. After setting up ambassador as an API gateway, I have tried a sample route with QOTM service for which when I send a http request to the route, I receive 503 Service unavailable in the response with body as = "no healthy upstream". But the same qotm service when I ran it as a stand alone docker container it worked for the route. Is there any thing specific to be taken care in kubernetes to setup ambassador.

```
 kubectl exec ambassador-589c864695-cg556 -- curl -v 10.101.64.22/qotm/*
> no healthy upstream*   Trying 10.101.64.22...
> * TCP_NODELAY set
>  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* > Connected to 10.101.64.22 (10.101.64.22) port 80 (#0)
> GET /qotm/* HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.101.64.22
> User-Agent: curl/7.63.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 19
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 03:54:16 GMT
< server: envoy
<
{ [19 bytes data]
100    19  100    19    0     0  19000      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19000
* Connection #0 to host 10.101.64.22 left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens generally when route service can't find host to redirect your request. It can be cause of even any simple typo or wrong on service/route configurations.

I would suggest you to check your service and route yaml files carefully, or just sharing manifests on your original post also can be helpful for you to get solution faster.

*Note* that Kubernetes doesn't recognize config error inside annotiation of service, so you will not see error when applying manifests.

But you can check logs for ambassador pods. Firstly list pods:

```
kubectl get pods -l service=ambassador
```

And then check logs of any of this pod to see if there is an error via

```
kubectl  logs -f ambassador-7784c84f8f-6wmlr
```

Please provide your files if still you have issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by installing WeaveNet as the CNI. I could not further analyse and find what was the issue when using Flannel.